# MySQL+PHPMYADMIN. Как найти и изменить часть значения по регулярному выражению?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Есть столбец в котором в строках пишутся цифры через запятую.
Тоесть так:
22,44,55,66,77
11,22,33,44,55

Мне требуется найти все строки, которых в начале стоит 22. И изменить это 22 на 33 например.
То есть регуляркой можно это выразить как ^22,
REGEXP_REPLACE не работает.
Как найти я вроде понял так как в mysql есть REGEXP фукнция, но как заменить потом? Чтобы поменялось 22 только в начале строки

Спасибо заранее

Comment: таких функций нет, либо обычным replace, либо долго и муторно определяя позиции вырезая и собирая строку назад. а все от того, что sql в принципе не предназначен для работы со строками через запятую. любые множественные данные должны выноситься в отдельную таблицу. (см. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0)

Comment: найти на 22 можно и через `like '22,%'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Под рукой нет MySQL, но это выглядит примерно так.

```
UPDATE tablename SET fieldname = INSERT(fieldname, 0, 2, '33') WHERE fieldname LIKE '22,%'
```

Если в функции INSERT индексом первого символа строки является 1, значит `INSERT(fieldname, 1, 2, '33')`

Comment: *Если в функции INSERT индексом первого символа строки является 1* Именно так.

Comment: Спасибо! То что нужно!!